# Removing the grey border around alt text with no image (chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I've looked around the web and have come across people providing a few examples on how this could be done but i'm struggling to get it to work on my site.

Here's the code's i've used.

```
<script>
jq('.productdetailbox .productdetailcont .addtocart').onerror(function() {
    jq(this).css('border','0');
})
</script>
```

On our site we have to replace $ with jq in order for any script to work.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you give more info on this? e.g. the html/css for this part of the page

Answer (score 0):

Replace `onerror` with `error` and it should work. [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/error/)

```
jq('.productdetailbox .productdetailcont .addtocart').error(function() {
    jq(this).css('border','none');
})
```

Comment: Hi @Patel, thanks for your answer but i did that and still no luck.